# What does the "select automatically" option do for a Run configuration in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

In the `Run Configuration...` dialog in Eclipse CDT there is the option to configure the project to build automatically before launch. Within this area there is a "Build configuration" dropdown which selects which configuration should be used for the build:

[image: Eclipse CDT Build Configuration]

This includes explicit options for the configurations in your projects, a "Use Active" option and a "Select Automatically" option.

The others are clear, but what does this last option do?

Comment: [_"**Each build system** provides it's **own mechanism** to figure out the toolchain for a config. Either it asks the user, or provides an **automated system**. For example Qt can map the QMAKE_XSPEC to a toolchain id, e.g. macx-clang to the gcc toolchain."_](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/Build/Doug)

Comment: @howlger - OK, but does that apply here? I'm not using a single toolchain and it isn't clear if that quote applies to above dialog (which seems more about choosing a build configuration based on (what?).

Comment: The toolchain creates an executable from the source code. [_"The standard CDT supports integration with the GNU toolchain. This includes GNU's make, gcc compiler, and gdb debugger utilities."_](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/concepts/cdt_c_before_you_begin.htm) I don't know if using the GNU toolchain `Select Automatically` is equivalent to `Debug`. Maybe `Select Automatically` only makes sense for some toolchains. I don't have an answer to your question. Hopefully, someone else can answer it.